# Liquibase - update native MS SQL script

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I'm using liquibase to update database.

I have file changelog-master.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
          <includeAll path="/src/main/resources/DBChangeLog/DDL/"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

in resource /src/main/resources/DBChangeLog/DDL/ I have one file with script MS SQL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id =         OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CONFIG]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONFIG](
        [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [OPERATOR] [XML] NOT NULL 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONFIG] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
        [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [DATA]
) ON [DATA]
END
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

when I run maven command I received error : mvn liquibase:update

ERROR:

```
src\main\resources\DBChangeLog\DDL\V2_20_0_0008__test.sql::raw::includeAll failed.  Error: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. [Failed SQL: SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CONFIG]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONFIG](
        [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,         
        [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [OPERATOR] [XML] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONFIG] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
        [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [DATA]
) ON [DATA]
END
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO]
```

Is it possible to run typical MS SQL script or liquibase will have problem with it ?

Comment: `GO` is not a SQL statement, so you can't put that into a script that is executed through JDBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this page: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html
for endDelimiter and splitStatements parameters.

Comment: The problem is with "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON" "SET ANSI_PADDING ON" to. It is strange that I can run this script on MS Server Management Studio.

Comment: It is possible that 'set' command is not supported in JDBC so Liquibase can't execute it. I got this issue with 'set' sqlplus instruction for Oracle database.